# Can we convert JSON file into Gherkin Script

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

By using selenium IDE extension I have recorded some steps and saved JSON file from the project. Now my requirement is to convert this JSON file into Gherkin Script. Can we do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? No. Gherkin is meant to capture requirements. Those requirements can also be made into automated tests. This is known as [Behavior-Driven Development](https://automationpanda.com/bdd/). Is there a reason why you need to use Gherkin?

Comment: Thanks Greg for the comment. For my project I have created my gherkin scripts manually by myself and interacted with the GLU code. But now my companies requirement is to check possibilities to generate the scripts automatically, for that they propose to look into the selenium IDE which is recording the user interaction in the web application and generating a JSON file. That's the reason converting JSON to GHERKIN script. I need to know the way to generate the gherkin scripts automatically by recording user interactions with the web application.

Comment: This isn't really possible. That isn't what Gherkin is meant for. Gherkin is, first and foremost, a tool for communicating requirements to people. Also it can be automated tests. Phrasing steps and scenarios in business terms is paramount. There is no way to infer the business process by which buttons are clicked in the user interface.